# Partition by fixed number of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.0

I like to know how I can partition a window by a fixed number of records.

Example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7df86).

```
CREATE TABLE Games 
(
 id serial primary key, 
 game_no integer not null, 
 points integer,
  constraint game_no unique (game_no)
);

INSERT INTO Games (game_no, points)
VALUES (3123, 5), (3126, 5), (3135, 8), (3128, null), (3130, 1), (3121, 11), 
(3132, 0), (3133, 4), (3110, 7), (3112, null), (3113, 12), (3125, 3),(3134, 8);
```

I want the sum of the points of three games combined, starting with the highest game number, descending ordered by the game number. Like this.

```
| GAME_NO | POINTS | SUM_THREE |
|---------|--------|-----------|
|    3135 |      8 |        20 |
|    3134 |      8 |        20 |
|    3133 |      4 |        20 |
|    3132 |      0 |         1 |
|    3130 |      1 |         1 |
|    3128 | (null) |         1 |
|    3126 |      5 |        13 |
|    3125 |      3 |        13 |
|    3123 |      5 |        13 |
|    3121 |     11 |        23 |
|    3113 |     12 |        23 |
|    3112 | (null) |        23 |
|    3110 |      7 |         7 |
```

How to accomplish this with a window function without using a subquery? I also can't use for example a with statement. It has to be one single query because of the external parser that will execute it (and I have no control over). It seems so simple and I'm breaking my head over it the last couple of days:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use row_number function divided by 3 to assign unique number to each group of 3 consecutive rows. Then use sum as analytical function on each group.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7df86/10)

```
with x(game_no, points, grp) as (
  select game_no, points,
         ceil(cast(row_number() over (order by game_no desc) as decimal)/ 3)
  from games
  )
select game_no, points,
       sum(points) over (partition by grp)
from x
order by game_no desc;
```

You can use inline view instead of with construct.

```
select game_no, points,
       sum(points) over (partition by grp)
from (
      select game_no, points,
             ceil(cast(row_number() over
                   (order by game_no desc) as decimal)/ 3) as grp
      from games
    ) as x
order by game_no desc;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7df86/10/0)**:

```
| GAME_NO | POINTS | SUM |
|---------|--------|-----|
|    3135 |      8 |  20 |
|    3134 |      8 |  20 |
|    3133 |      4 |  20 |
|    3132 |      0 |   1 |
|    3130 |      1 |   1 |
|    3128 | (null) |   1 |
|    3126 |      5 |  13 |
|    3125 |      3 |  13 |
|    3123 |      5 |  13 |
|    3121 |     11 |  23 |
|    3113 |     12 |  23 |
|    3112 | (null) |  23 |
|    3110 |      7 |   7 |
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to accomplish the same result without using the 'with' construction? I will edit my post to make it more clear I need a 'single statement' solution.

Comment: The parser does accept the inline view. And I learned a lot from your queries:) Thanks.

Comment: I find this query to be very inefficient – can it be sped up with an index?

Comment: I found inline view very helpful. Added one more attribute to perform this calculation per department in my organization :)